# Running wamp 3.1.3 Apache 2.4.33 fails with make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80 NT Kernel and System has taken it

Tags: windows, apache, sockets, wamp, port

I have done a fresh installation of wamp server, checked all distributable dependencies, killed skype, ran as Administrator...

It fails to start Apache...

In event log it fails with following 4 messages:

1. > The Apache service named  reported the following error:
   >
   > > > AH00015: Unable to open logs     .
2. > The Apache service named  reported the following error:
   >
   > > > AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down     .
3. > The Apache service named  reported the following error:
   >
   > > > (OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80     .
4. > The Apache service named  reported the following error:
   >
   > > > (OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80

So port 80 is taken, and whatever is using it has to be killed...

Here's the twist, it is used by `NT Kernel and System` which the way I read this is Windows core. Now obviously I can't just kill windows and begone with it...

[image]

I am not sure how to debug this further... **How to figure out which system service (or whatever) I need to disable to free up the port 80 when it is marked as used by `NT Kernel and System`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out by myself by running `cmd` as admin and using `netstat -bano`

My mistake was that I had disabled IIS and Skype so I thought I was safe, turns out it was `SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)` that had to be also killed.

[image]

After this wamp turned green.